# node.js forEach Array of objects getting undefined value inside the loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb

Getting unexplained "undefined" when I loop through an array of objects (this is coming from mongo document that has a nested document)

```
user.assistantOf.forEach(function(u){   
    console.log(u);
    console.log(u.id +' '+ u.test + ' ' + u.status);

        arr.push(u.id);
})
```

```
{ test: 'test1',                                                                                           
  status: 'active',                                                                                        
  id: '58aa50fb6b364b150405a183' }  

58aa50fb6b364b150405a183 undefined undefined  

{ test: 'test2',                                                                                           
  status: 'active',                                                                                        
  id: '58cff0e0c5aa2b0011ddbf3e' }    

58cff0e0c5aa2b0011ddbf3e undefined undefined
```

So, the loop can access object properties, so it seems - it prints id, but does not access status and test properties. I really need the status of each object.

Comment: If you are using mongoose, you can run `u.toObject()` to get the js object.

Answer (score -1):

OMG, I'm an idiot.

I did not have "status" in my mongoose model of this array.

So, here's how it should be, and it works now:

assistantOf: [{
      _id:false,
      id: {type: String},
      status: {type: String}
   }],